# Javascript: image onclick then slide big image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really like this slider sample [HERE!](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/FullWidthImageSlider/). But I want to do is assign next/previous onclick command on images display on right side like this:

[image: Sample Image]
Instead of clicking those DOTS. I want to assign the onclick EVENT on images(RED BOXES).

How can I tweak that one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide some code you have worked on. A www.codepen.io example would be amazing.

Comment: @derek_duncan [HERE](http://codepen.io/Unknownymous/pen/dLKDe) Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I've simply changed the `$navDots` variable to point to the images on line 90 of js.

```
var navDots = $('.nav-images');
this.$navDots = navDots.children( 'img' );
```

#### Then use this HTML:

```
<div class="nav-images">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city" alt="img01" width="100px"/>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/business" alt="img02" width="100px"/>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/technics" alt="img03" width="100px"/>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people" alt="img04" width="100px"/>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" alt="img05" width="100px"/>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" width="100px"/>
</div>
```

Hope it helps! Please see codepen example as well!. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/corjw

Comment: yes it works!! thank you sir! you save my day! last question.

Comment: and one more thing sir.. how can i remove those NEXT/PREVIOUS buttons sir?? I did remove the CSS it works but when I reach the last image then go back it show the NEXT but in LEFT side

Comment: Yes, remove line 62 of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer***

Please do link to the non-minified source of the plugin, so you can modify that file directly. Currently, the plugin handles all the elements inside the `#cbp-fwslider` area. It may not be advisable to hack from outside, which is what this solution is...

**Solution**

It looks like you can mimic this by hiding the dots (which is what the plugin uses by default) and using your two elements to trigger click events on the dots. The currently active dot is indicated by a `cbp-fwcurrent`, so something like `$('#cbp-fwslider .cbp-fwdots .cbp-fwcurrent')` would select the current dot. Use jQuery's [*next()*](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [*prev()*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) calls check if the relevant dot exists, and then do a `$el.trigger('click')`.

**Code Outline (untested)**

```
$('#fwdButton').click(function() {
  var $dot = $('#cbp-fwslider .cbp-fwdots .cbp-fwcurrent'),
      $nextDot = $dot.next();
  if ($nextDot) {
    $nextDot.trigger('click');
  }
});
```

`

Comment: thank you for your informative response sir and my bad for linking the non minified source..

Comment: You're welcome! No sweat - it's just easier for people to answer questions when all the material is readily available...